# How to end an infinite akka stream

Tags: scala, terminate, akka-stream

I'm new to Akka Streams but have a case where I want to use it to look for permutations from an infinite source. A simplified example with a finite source could look like this.

```
val future = Source(1 to 100)
    .map { i => if (i % 20 == 0) println(i); i }
    .filter(_ == 42)
    .runWith(Sink.fold[Int, Int](0)(Keep.right))
```

This exemple outputs:

```
20
40
60
80
100
```

I'm obviously fine with the source getting past `42` but I don't want to exhaust the entire stream before being able to get the result.

```
val result: Int = Await.result(future, 1.second)
result should be(42)
```

Question is, how should I end the stream when I've found what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val future = Source(1 to 100)
    .map { i => if (i % 20 == 0) println(i); i }
    .filter(_ == 42)
    .runWith(Sink.head)
```

Answer (score 2):

Generalizing  to `N` values, e.g. the 10 values greater than or equal to 42, you can use [`grouped`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/?_ga=1.122802763.1917589872.1429296441#akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow):

```
val N = 10

val future : Future[Seq[Int]] = 
  Source(1 to 100).map { i => if (i % 20 == 0) println(i); i }
                  .filter(_ >= 42)
                  .grouped(N)
                  .runWith(Sink.head)
```